# Shell script to get AWS Org Root ID fails when running in Github actions workflow

Tags: github-actions

I have the following step in the GitHub workflow that creates an organization in an AWS account and sets AWS Organization Root ID. The problem is that this step fails in Github workflow with exit code 254, but works if I run it via local command line. It's failing because the AWS CLI is returning an error `An error occurred (AWSOrganizationsNotInUseException) when calling the DescribeOrganization operation: Your account is not a member of an organization.` which expected and the script is supposed to handle it. I'm redirecting all output to stdout, so I'm really scratching my head here trying to figure out why the script is exiting instead of handling failures.

```yaml
      - name: Setup Organization
        id: org
        run: |
            response=$(aws organizations describe-organization 2>&1)

            if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                if echo ${response} | grep -q "AWSOrganizationsNotInUseException"; then
                    echo "Creating organization..."

                    aws organizations create-organization --feature-set "ALL"
                fi
            fi

            echo "::set-output name=ROOT_ID::$(aws organizations list-roots --query 'Roots[0].[Id]' --output text)"
        shell: bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Github Actions executes bash scripts in fail-fast mode (`bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}`) by default. I had to turn it off to take full control by passing `bash {0}` to the shell parameter. The following step works in the workflow now in case anyone is struggling with a similar issue.

```yaml
      - name: Setup Organization
        id: org
        run: |
            response=$(aws organizations describe-organization 2>&1)

            if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                if echo ${response} | grep -q "AWSOrganizationsNotInUseException"; then
                    echo "Creating organization..."

                    aws organizations create-organization --feature-set "ALL"
                fi
            fi

            echo "::set-output name=ROOT_ID::$(aws organizations list-roots --query 'Roots[0].[Id]' --output text)"
        shell: bash {0}
```